# using HTTP Post method how to make login page in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm have created a Login view. Everytime I login it gives me login Success message will be displayed.  even if I enter wrong username and password.I am created login page static.The menctioned link is sample web services link. This is the method I'm using right now:Please give me any idea.Thanks in advance.

```
loginPage.m
```

-

```
(IBAction)login:(id)sender

{

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username",@"password"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];


[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP://URL"]]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];


[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


if (conn)

{

NSLog(@"connection successful");

}

else

{


NSLog(@"Failed");


}

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

{

[textField resignFirstResponder];

return YES;

}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{

}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{

[receivedData setLength:0];

// NSURL *theURL=[response URL];

}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

if(receivedData)

{

NSLog(@"success",[receivedData length]);

}

else

{

NSLog(@"Success",[receivedData length]);

}

}
```

Comment: whats ur problem i cant understand from question??

Comment: Have you tried implementing `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:`? (rhetoric question!)  ;)

Comment: AFNetworking is good solution for connecting your app with the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your Url.php?&Username=%@&Password=%@",username,password];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);
        NSString *str1 = @"1";
        if ([str isEqualToString:str1 ])
        {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Successfully" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Try Again" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Later" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
            alert.tag = 1;
            [alert show];
        }
```

Don't need to use JSON you can do this without JSON in a esay way!!!

Comment: your code not working properly.The following message will be displayed if i click the login button.

Comment: Username=<UITextField: 0x719a9b0; frame = (140 88; 160 30); text = 'surya'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x719c210>; layer = <CALayer: 0x719ab00>>&Password=<UITextField: 0x7193cd0; frame = (140 148; 160 30); text = 'ios'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM;

Comment: gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7199870>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7193e70>>
2013-09-02 18:17:05.247 PadosiApp[3665:11303] responseData: (null)
2013-09-02 18:17:05.248 PadosiApp[3665:11303] responseData:

Comment: This code example cannot be a solution. It even shouldn't be an answer. Too many quirks in just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertView show];

}


- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    @try {

        if([[txtUserName text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Пожалуйста заполните все поля!!!" :@"Авторизация не удолась!"];
        } else {

            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",[txtUserName text],[txtPassword text]];


            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:xxxxxxxx.xxx/?"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];




            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSData *responseData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:urlData];
                NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


                if([jsonObject objectForKey:@"error"])
                {
                    [self alertStatus:@"" :@""];

                } else {

                    [self alertStatus:@"" :@""];
                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
    }

    [txtUserName resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
-(void)webservice_Call
{
NSString *urlString=@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=10.369&lon=122.5896";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;


NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

NSDictionary *resDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:Nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post Method for iOS 9 Version

```
    NSMutableDictionary *post = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                
    [post setValue:@“25” forKey:@"user_id"];

    NSArray* notifications = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:post, nil];
            
    NSError *writeError = nil;
           
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:notifications options:kNilOptions error:&writeError];
            
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]];
           
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
           
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your/url]]];
          
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
           
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length" ];
           
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
           
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
           
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
                
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
     
    // Create a data task object to perform the data downloading.
            
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     
        data = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:urlData];

        NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    }];
          
    [task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)apiCode
{
    NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:url...project_id=1&user_id=58&question=%@&send_enquiry=%@",self.txtTitle.text,self.txtQuestion.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);
    NSString *str1 = @"success";
    if ([str isEqualToString:str1 ])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Successfully" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Try Again" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Later" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
        alert.tag = 1;
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: just add above method to login button with parameters you want to pass and i am very thankful that Mr.Kapil Maherswari code help me to resolve my problem