# Passing parameter in url for GET method using afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

i have url in which query is executed.

```
https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/?query=where UserName='abc'&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&filterResultByColumns=true
```

i am escaping the remaining part after tenant url like this,

```
 NSString *requestUrl = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?query=where UserName='%@'&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&filterResultByColumns=true",<TENANT_URL>,userCredential.userName]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    requestUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",baseurl,requestUrl];
```

Here is my GET request.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        AFHTTPResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

            serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];


        manager.responseSerializer = serializer;
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",URL];


    [manager GET:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                    NSError* error = nil;
                    NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:responseObject

                                          options:kNilOptions 
                                          error:&error];
                    success(json);
                }
                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                         failure(error);
                     }];
```

But i always getting a 400 Bad request error. I think problem is with "query=where ..". But i am not sure. How can i parse the URL. I tested with "POSTMAN" in Chrome. It works perfectly. But it throws me an error when i run the app.

**Error:**

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0xb7ac2b0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/?query=where UserName='abc'&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&filterResultByColumns=true&url=https%3A%2F%2F<BASE_URL>%2F%2F<TENANT_URL>%2F%3F?query=where%2DUserName%3D%27abc%27%26companyId%3D%26page%3D1%26pageSize%3D25%26filterResultByColumns%3Dtrue, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xb7e6910> { URL: https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/?query=where UserName='abc'&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&filterResultByColumns=true&url=https%3A%2F%2F<BASE_URL>%2F%2F<TENANT_URL>%2F%3F?query=where%2DUserName%3D%27abc%27%26companyId%3D%26page%3D1%26pageSize%3D25%26filterResultByColumns%3Dtrue } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Fri, 17 Jan 2014 05:29:56 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18573417/2439156

Comment: The error you've posted seems to indicate that you haven't put actual values into your URL - it's showing: `https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/?query=where UserName='abc'&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&filterResultByColumns=true&url=https%3A%2F%2F<BASE_URL>%2F%2F<TENANT_URL>%2F%3F?query=where%2DUserName%3D%27abc%27%26companyId%3D%26page%3D1%26pageSize%3D25%26filterResultByColumns%3Dtrue`, which doesn't contain any real web address to hit. Are you sure you're passing the URL you've created to AFNetworking?

Comment: Yes it has real web address. I posted here with dummy URL. I browsed the url in chrome. It seems working. But when i run it on simulator. i am getting this error.

Comment: Passing `query=where UserName='abc'` as part of a URL seems like a bad idea - is this part of a raw SQL query? If so, your web service really needs some attention, as it's likely vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. It also doesn't look like it's escape correctly, as you still have a space, '' marks, and an equals symbol in there.

Comment: When _decoding_ the percent-encoded query component logged in the error message, I get this: `where-UserName='abc'&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&filterResultByColumns=true`. The hyphen "-" after "where" is certainly not correct. So, I'm wondering *how* you precent encoded the original query component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like there are a number of issues with the URL you're constructing, and the way you're passing (or not passing) parameters into AFNetworking. You don't need to construct your query string yourself, as AFNetworking will do that for you. As mentioned in my comment above, passing `query=where UserName='abc'` as part of a URL seems like a bad idea. However, here's a quick example of how you'd call AFNetworking's `GET` method if your URL was slightly different:

```
// URL format: https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/?username=abc&companyId=&page=1&pageSize=25&filterResultByColumns=true

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithScheme:@"https" host:BASE_URL path:TENANT_URL];

[manager GET:[baseURL absoluteString] 
  parameters:@{ @"username": @"abc",
                @"companyId": @"example",
                @"page": @1,
                @"pageSize": @25,
                @"filterResultByColumns": @YES }
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // handle success
            }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            // handle failure
            }];
```

If you pass your parameters into the GET method, AFNetworking will construct the query string for you.

Comment: i got the response.But it seems to be incorrect. Because when i browse the url https://<BASE_URL>/<TENANT_URL>/. i get dummy response which doesn't take any parameters that i am passing.

Comment: James, you are saying "passing parameters as part of a URL seems a bad idea", why? IMHO, this is not sufficient to exploit SQL injection.

Comment: I'm not saying that passing parameters as a whole is a bad idea - of course, that's the way GET requests work. I was specifically referring to this parameter: `query=where UserName='abc'` - it looks as though it's intended to be used as part of an SQL SELECT query on the server side.

Comment: Just curious, did `@"filterResultByColumns": @YES` construct `filterResultByColumns=1` or `filterResultByColumns=true` in your URL?