# How to set global parameters for requests with AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking to make requests and want a certain parameter to go out with every request.

Specifically, every request requires the `api_key` to be sent with it -- e.g. Lets say my API key is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, a request might look like: http://url-of-api/endpoint?param1=thing&param2=other-thing&**api_key=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz**

I was wondering how in AFNetworking to specify that this `api_key=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` parameter be included in every request *in addition to* parameters specific to that request? Perhaps in the configuration of `AFJSONRequestSerializer`?

Comment: Here's an article on stack overflow that will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178697/passing-parameter-in-url-for-get-method-using-afnetworking

Comment: I get how to pass parameters to requests. I was wondering if there's an AFNetworking way to specify certain parameters to be passed with each request - sort of how you can specify what type of content should be returned for your response serializer ( `serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];`).

Answer (score -1):

Not that I've seen.  When I'm using key like GoogleMaps, I use a parameter structure like the one shown in the SO article:

```
    parameters:@{ @"username": @"abc",
            @"companyId": @"example",
            @"page": @1,
            @"pageSize": @25,
            @"filterResultByColumns": @YES }
```

or in your case:

```
    parameters:@{ @"username": @"abc",
            @"companyId": @"example",
            @"page": @1,
            @"pageSize": @25,
            @"key": @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
            @"filterResultByColumns": @YES }
```